# CSS3PIE doesn't work with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, css3pie

I have checked other problems related to PIE integration with wordpress, but no result.

I have tried to add the entire url in the css behevior but, no result.

This is my code:

```
#website {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px #000;
    behavior: url(http://www.example.com/path/to/my/pie/htc/file/myurl.htc)
}
```

But no result.

I am using the latest version of WordPress.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this path? Specifically the overabundance of dots?

Comment: no, i'm not using dots, it is an example, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must put the entire website url in behavior, to have it working with Wordpress.
2. If the problem prospers, you can install a simple plugin: IE CSS3 Support. It uses PIE v1.

If you want to make PIE v2 functions working with this plugin:

After you the install of plugin, you can download the PIE v2(latest) an upload it in wp-content/plugins/ie-css3-support/markup (please rename the old pie to have it as a restore file). After that, you can open /wp-content/plugins/ie-css3-support/core.php file and add in the array, the other css values, that are available in the PIE v2.

**EDIT**

**Plugin URL:** http://wordpress.org/plugins/ie-css3-support/

**ATTENTION:** If you are using z-index in the page who uses css3, you MUST increase it! *(if it is not a big number)*

***Hope it helps you!***